# Python convert list of tuples to json

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have list of tuples like :

```
[('a', '76', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('b', '14', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('c', '99', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('d', '62', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('e', '112', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('f', '78', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('g', '20', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('h', '14', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('i', '23', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('a', '45', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('b', '36', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('c', '22', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('d', '69', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('e', '11', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('f', '118', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('g', '29', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('h', '34', '20190208011803-0500'),
 ('i', '63', '20190208011803-0500')]
```

The third element of all the tuples are the same. I am trying to convert this list into a dictionary in the following way:

```
{timestamp: 20190208011713-0500,
  'a' : 76,
  'b' : 14,
  'c' : 99,
  'd' : 62,
  'e' : 112,
  'f' : 78,
  'g' : 20,
  'h' : 14,
  'i' : 23}
```

**UPDATE:**

As of now I am doing it manually but I have around 1000's of tuples in a list with the same timestamp, but sometimes I do also have different timestamps. I am trying to automate this process by writing a function as I need to re-use the code again and again for multiple list of tuples to create list of dictionaries but I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated?

```
[{'timestamp': '20190208011713-0500',
  'a' : 76,
  'b' : 14,
  'c' : 99,
  'd' : 62,
  'e' : 112,
  'f' : 78,
  'g' : 20,
  'h' : 14,
  'i' : 23}, 
  {'timestamp': '20190208011803-0500',
  'a' : 45,
  'b' : 36,
  'c' : 22,
  'd' : 69,
  'e' : 11,
  'f' : 118,
  'g' : 29,
  'h' : 34,
  'i' : 63}]
```

Comment: Side note: Python 2.7 will reach it's end of life in [10 months time](https://pythonclock.org/). If this is a new project, you should really be building this in Python 3. My answer below is fully compatible with both Python 2 and 3, so you can take it with you.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn I'll keep that in mind. Yes, I am using python 2.7 for this project and having you said that I will migrate my code to python3 from python2. And your solution works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the timestamp is guaranteed to be the same, or otherwise you don't care if it isn't, then just use:

```
result = {'timestamp': your_list[0][-1]}
result.update(tup[:2] for tup in your_list)
```

The second line takes the first two elements of each tuple, and passes those directly to the [`dict.update()` method](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update). Like the [`dict()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict), that method accepts an iterable of `(key, value)` tuples, and with slicing, that's what you have already.

Demo:

```
>>> result = {'timestamp': your_list[0][-1]}
>>> result.update(tup[:2] for tup in your_list)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
{'a': '76',
 'b': '14',
 'c': '99',
 'd': '62',
 'e': '112',
 'f': '78',
 'g': '20',
 'h': '14',
 'i': '23',
 'timestamp': '20190208011713-0500'}
```

If speed is of the essence, you can use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to do the fetching, and use the [Python 3 version of `map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.map) to apply it when updating:

```
from operator import itemgetter
try:
    # forward compatibility with Python 3
    from future_builtins import map
except ImportError:
    pass

result = {'timestamp': your_list[0][-1]}
result.update(map(itemgetter(0, 1), your_list))
```

With those changes the whole `result.update()` loop is executed in native C code.

If your timestamps are not guaranteed to be the same and you need to produce a list, you need to split out (group) your tuples by timestamp. If your input is at least *grouped* (all entries with the same timestamp appear consecutively), then you can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do the grouping. The way you then build each dictionary remains the same; we can use the `itemgetter()` calleble here too to produce the grouping key:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
try:
    # forward compatibility with Python 3
    from future_builtins import map
except ImportError:
    pass

def group_timestamp(timestamp, group):
    d = {'timestamp': timestamp}
    d.update(map(itemgetter(0, 1), group))
    return d

result = [group_timestamp(ts, group) for ts, group in groupby(your_list, itemgetter(2))]
```

If they are not grouped, then I'd *not* sort the input. You want to shunt them into each timestamp group linearly, using a dictionary to do the grouping, then just sort the values of that dictionary when producing the output:

```
groups = {}
for key, value, ts in your_list:
    if ts not in groups:
        groups[ts] = {'timestamp': ts}
    groups[ts][key] = value

result = sorted(groups.values(), key=itemgetter('timestamp'))
```

This gives you the grouped dicitonaries in timestamp order. If output order doesn't matter, just use `result = list(groups.values())`.

Comment: The above code works fine but only for same timestamp not for different timestamps.

Comment: @akashbachu: which is why the answer starts with *If the timestamp is guaranteed to be the same,*

Comment: @akashbachu: are the timestamps *grouped* at least? Or do can they appear in any order?

Comment: They appear in random order.

Comment: @akashbachu: right, I've given options for when they are grouped and when they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Accounting for changing timestamps:

```
lst = [('a', '76', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('b', '14', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('c', '99', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('d', '62', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('e', '112', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('f', '78', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('g', '20', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('h', '14', '20190208011713-0500'),
    ('i', '23', '20190208011713-0500')]

dict = {}

for tuple in lst:
    if tuple[2] in dict:
        dict[tuple[2]][tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
    else:
        dict[tuple[2]] = {}
        dict[tuple[2]][tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'20190208011713-0500': {'a': '76',
  'b': '14',
  'c': '99',
  'd': '62',
  'e': '112',
  'f': '78',
  'g': '20',
  'h': '14',
  'i': '23'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tups = [('a', '76', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('b', '14', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('c', '99', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('d', '62', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('e', '112', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('f', '78', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('g', '20', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('h', '14', '20190208011713-0500'),
 ('i', '23', '20190208011713-0500')]


def to_dict(tups):
    my_dict = {element[0]: element[1] for element in tups}
    my_dict['timestamp'] = tups[-1][2] 
    return my_dict

m_d = to_dict(tups)
print(m_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is the following:

```
return_dict = dict([item[:2] for item in your_list])
return_dict["timestamp"] = your_list[0][2]
```